# CSV with multiple header rows; import into mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

I've got a CSV file with two sets of data in it [its pulled of a temperature logger]. I'm wondering if there's a way to import the first two rows as one set of data and the rest as a second set of data. I'm familiar with PHP, but have never had to do anything like this. I've attached a subset of data below. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Ajay

```
Serial Number,Model,Name,Number,Time of Reading,Sample Rate,Start Time
910000000ebeaa4,DS1922T,SRBA04-240909  ,beaa-TNTVLPRP54,9/30/09 16:52,1,9/24/09 18:59
Sample #,Date/Time,Temp ¡F,Temp ¡C,,,
1,"Thu, Sep, 24, 06:59, PM",82.4,28,,,
2,"Thu, Sep, 24, 07:00, PM",83.3,28.5,,,
3,"Thu, Sep, 24, 07:01, PM",83.3,28.5,,,
4,"Thu, Sep, 24, 07:02, PM",83.3,28.5,,,
5,"Thu, Sep, 24, 07:03, PM",83.3,28.5,,,
6,"Thu, Sep, 24, 07:04, PM",83.3,28.5,,,
7,"Thu, Sep, 24, 07:05, PM",83.3,28.5,,,
8,"Thu, Sep, 24, 07:06, PM",83.3,28.5,,,
9,"Thu, Sep, 24, 07:07, PM",83.3,28.5,,,
10,"Thu, Sep, 24, 07:08, PM",83.3,28.5,,,
```

solution, based on deceze's comment below

deceze, thanks. this works [as does the sql insert]. much appreciated.

```
<?php
$fhandle = fopen('1.csv', 'r');

$device_header = fgetcsv($fhandle, 1000, ',');                      
$device_data = fgetcsv($fhandle,1000,',');                          

$device = array_combine($device_header, $device_data);          

$data_header = fgetcsv($fhandle,1000,',');                          

$dataset = array();                                             
    while ($data = fgetcsv($fhandle,1000,',')) {  
        $dataset[] = array_combine($data_header, $data);        
}

fclose($fhandle);

?>
```

Comment: `expects array, boolean given` means that a call to `fgetcsv($fhandle)` probably returned `false` at some point. You'll have to put some more error handling in, I'm just showing you the general approach. Do not just copy and paste code without understanding what it does. As for SQL, you should be able to insert that data with the resulting `$set1` and `$set2` arrays. I don't understand what you want to append, but again, if you try to understand the code you can customize it to meet your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
$fhandle = fopen('/path/to/input.csv', 'r');

$headers = fgetcsv($fhandle);  // reads first line
$set1 = array_combine($headers, fgetcsv($fhandle));  // reads second line

$set2 = array();
$headers = fgetcsv($fhandle);  // reads third line
while ($data = fgetcsv($fhandle)) {  // reads all following lines
    $set2[] = array_combine($headers, $data);
}

fclose($fhandle);

/*
$set1 == array('Serial Number' => '910000000ebeaa4', 'Model' => ...);
$set2 == array(
    array('Sample #' => 1, 'Date/Time' => 'Thu, Sep, 24, 06:59, PM', ...),
    ...
);
*/
```